# How long does it take to open public beta?

Tags: discussion

How much time do we have before it launches to the public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've extended the private betas to last about **three weeks total.** In actuality, if you call the initial launch "week one", the evaluations and discussion happen near the end of week three. We extended the private beta another week because the logistics of launching a private beta and getting everyone together to wrap everything up in two weeks made the deliberations all but impossible.

Comment: Interesting. When did the extension happen, and was it related to what happened with Computer Graphics/Open Science? I'm glad that the period's longer; I'm just a bit curious as to the reason for the change.

Comment: @HDE226868 This is the first private beta under the change. It wasn't related to anything in particular. It was just a way to give us more time to work through the process.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one week, but if we don't have the site's scope down by then, I would be tempted to [request another week](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/308/46) in private beta. We don't want to let the whole world in if we don't know what's on-topic and what isn't.

Comment: Is it a matter of site's scope or post quantity?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt When I made that post on SR, it was about post quality. Here, I would imagine it would be able scope. However, if we're staying in private beta for at least three weeks like Robert said, this shouldn't be as much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Private beta usually lasts one week, or longer if it takes longer to give the site a good set of content and users to carry the beta when it goes public.

Open Source's beta lasted two weeks, to allow us to populate the site a little bit more.

**tl;dr:** not long.